# Storing changes to stored procedure and triggers in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, trigger, postgresql-9.1

I want a mechanism where I can store/track changes in stored procedure and triggers.

I want to track these logs in some table. What is the best possible way ?

Comment: Do you want to track the changes to the _source code_ of the stored procedures? Then use a version control system like Subversion or Git. And make sure you only deploy in a controlled way (or even consider a tool like Liquibase or Flyway)

Comment: You can't define triggers on system tables like `pg_proc`, so I'm afraid you'll have to do this outside PostgreSQL its self.

Comment: Can I track for only stored procedures then for a database? I want something where an event/trigger occurs if a person changes / creates / drops a stored procedure.

Comment: I am not sure but IIRC 9.4 will have trigger logging

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/event-trigger-definition.html I guess you can build your solution on this, you can write from the procedure defined from the trigger.